# Compatible versions of zookeeper and zkclient

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am in the middle of troubleshooting spark submit issue and noticed that my zookeeper version is 3.4.6. My client code is using zkclient 0.3. I am not sure if both are compatible. Can anyone please provide me this compatible list or let me know where to look for

Comment: What happens when you perform a spark-submit?

Comment: @eboni, Sorry for the delayed reply. I was working on spark submit issue and resolved it. Initial problem was it was not going into "Running" state. And there was no exceptions or errors in application logs. So i was trying to check any version conflicts in the jars that i push.

Comment: Awesome that you found a solution!